# Validation Rules are not working for change password in Yii php?

Tags: php, validation, yii, passwords

I am creating change password functionality, all things are working fine except the old password validation rule.here is my code

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('is_active', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('first_name, joining_date,last_name, employee_code, username, password, role', 'required','on'=>array('create')),     
        array('employee_code', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('username','email'),      
        array('username','valid_username','on'=>array('create')),

        //array('username', 'contraints', 'readOnly'=>true, 'on'=>'update'),

        array('currentPassword, newPassword, newPasswordRepeat', 'required','on'=>array('change')),
        //array('newPassword', 'length', 'min' => 6, 'max'=>20, 'message'=>Yii::t("translation", "{attribute} is too short.")),
        //array('newPassword','ext.SPasswordValidator.SPasswordValidator', 'preset' => 'strong', 'max' => 41),
        array('newPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'newPasswordRepeat','on'=>array('change')),

        array('currentPassword', 'equalPasswords','on'=>array('change')),

        array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements(),'on'=>array('forgotPassword')),
        array('joining_date', 'safe'),
        array('user_id, first_name, last_name, employee_code, username, password, role, joining_date, pending_regular_leave, pending_medical_leave, allocated_regular_leave, allocated_medical_leave, is_active', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

My change password function is

```
public function equalPasswords($attribute, $params)
{
    $user = Users::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id); 
    if ($user->password != md5($attribute))
    {
       $this->addError($attribute, 'Old password is incorrect.');
    }   
}
```

**Update method**

:

```
public function actionChange()
{
        $model=new Users;
        $model->setScenario('change');

    if (isset($_POST['Users'])) {
        $model->setAttributes($_POST['Users']);                     
        if($model->validate())
            {       
                $pass = md5($_POST['Users']['newPassword']);            
                $userModel = Users::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
                $userModel->password = $pass; 
                $data = $userModel->update();
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success',"Password changed successfully!");
            }
        }

$this->render('change_password', array('model'=>$model,true));
}
```

when i try to change password with all the correct parameters (correct old password,new password,retype password) it update the password but also shows me error that your **old password does not correct** .please help me to resolve this as i am new to Yii. 
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you can try once.

```
$user = Users::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id); 
if ($user->password != md5($this->attributes['currentPassword']))
{
     $this->addError($attribute, 'Old password is incorrect.');
}
```

change `md5($attribute)` to `md5($this->attributes['currentPassword']`

And add this in your rules

```
public function rules()
{
    public $currentPassword; 
    // your rules here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the validator you receive the attribute name, not the value in `$attribute`. To get the value you'd have to:

```
$value = $this->$attribute;
```

Comment: Well, then do some debugging: Add a `echo $user->password; echo $this->$attribute;exit;` in your `equalPasswords()` method. This should help you to track down the issue.

Comment: now validation are working fine when i commented the update method its works but when i uncomment the method 

`$data = $userModel->update();` it throws me the same error i have updated my question with the update function.

Comment: Ok, but this is a different question now. Your original problem with failed validation is solved. The code you have in your controller is actually not so good. You should load the user model first, then assign the attributes there.